# Where is SHA256_Update() defined in openssl/crypto?

Tags: cryptography, openssl

I know that SHA256_Update() is implemented in libcrypto under openssl, yet, a simple grep can't find its definition:

```
$ ack SHA256_Update
fips/fips_standalone_sha1.c
76:     SHA256_Update(md_ctx,key,len);
87:    SHA256_Update(md_ctx,pad,SHA256_CBLOCK);
92:    SHA256_Update(o_ctx,pad,SHA256_CBLOCK);
100:    SHA256_Update(o_ctx,buf,sizeof buf);
154:        SHA256_Update(&md_ctx,buf,l);

evp/m_sha1.c
114:    { return SHA256_Update(ctx->md_data,data,count); }

sha/sha256.c
58:     SHA256_Update(&c,d,n);
71:     SHA256_Update(&c,d,n);
78:{   return SHA256_Update (c,data,len);   }
116:#define     HASH_UPDATE             SHA256_Update
```

All these instances are where the function gets called, but not its definition. Yet, if I do "nm libcrypto.so |grep SHA256_Update", the entry can be found.

Weird...

Anyone could shed some light here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

md32_common.h is a "poor-man's template" for C.
It defines the structure of a general update function for any hash algorithm. Each algorithm provides the name for this general structure.

So in md32_common.h you will find this:

```
int HASH_UPDATE (HASH_CTX *c, const void *data_, size_t len)
```

And in sha/sha256.c you will find:

```
#define HASH_UPDATE             SHA256_Update
```

So that when md32_common.h is included, you get the function SHA256_Update defined.

At the beginning of md32_common.h you will find a more complete explanation with an example.

Comment: I did see this `#define` yesterday, but didn't pay enough attention to it. Because usually the usage is something like `#define unknown known`, for example, `#define BUFFER_SIZE 256`. So when I saw `#define HASH_UPDATE  SHA256_Update` yesterday, I thought `SHA256_Update` must be defined/implemented somewhere else. But today, you answer makes me think of the basics of a `#define` macro. Essentially, it is a textual substitution. With this in mind, it is not that hard to understand the code in crypto. Thank you, Omri!